# Working on an import of an excel form data

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a tool to automate the update of a new template with existing data from an old template in excel. I have it working with one range but I have multiple ranges in the template. I can't get it to work using

```
Set xRng1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
xWb.Activate
Set xRng2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
xRng1.Copy xRng2
xRng2.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
xAddWb.Close False
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in a Loop and use OnError with the Cancel button to exit.

```vb
    
    On Error GoTo done
    Do
        xAddWb.Activate
        Set xRng1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", _
                    Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)

        xWb.Activate
        Set xRng2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", _
                    Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        xRng1.Copy xRng2
        xRng2.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Loop
done:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "I'm done"
    xAddWb.Close False
```